# CakePHP remove HTML from plain text email

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the email componant in my cakephp app (2.2) to send emails to subscribed people when a new article is added in my app.

I use TinyMCE to allow admin users to format text which results in some formatting HTML being saved in the database (which is fine) however I want to email the opted in users the whole article in email format, both html and plain text when a new article is added. This works fine for the html version but how can I strip the html from the plain text version whilst keeping it in the html version? Heres my code so far:

```
public function admin_add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->NewsArticle->create();
        if ($this->NewsArticle->save($this->request->data)) {

            // If is a tech alart - send email
            if ($this->request->data['NewsCategory']['NewsCategory']['0'] == '2') {

                // Email users who have opted in to webform updates
                $usersToEmail = $this->NewsArticle->query("SELECT username, tech_email FROM users WHERE tech_email = 1");

                // Loop throughh all opt'ed in users
                foreach ($usersToEmail as $user) {

                    $this->Email->template = 'newTechAlert';
                    $this->Email->from    = 'Client Area <clientarea@someurl.co.uk>';
                    $this->Email->to      = $user['users']['username'];
                    $this->Email->subject = 'New Technical Alert';
                    // Send as both HTML and Text
                                            $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

                    // Set vars for email
                    $this->set('techAlertTitle', $this->request->data['NewsArticle']['title']);

                    ##  NEED TO STRIP THE HTML OUT FOR NONE HTML EMAILS HERE - BUT HOW???
                    $this->set('techAlertBody', $this->request->data['NewsArticle']['body']);


                    $this->set('user', $user['users']['username']);
                    $this->Email->send();

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the php `strip_tags` method
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
//HTML VERSION
$this->set('techAlertHtmlBody', $this->request->data['NewsArticle']['body']);

//PLAIN TEXT VERSION
$this->set('techAlertPlainBody', strip_tags($this->request->data['NewsArticle']['body']));
```

You can also pass a second param to the function to still allow line breaks or href tags.

Comment: Ah, ofcourse very simple. Think I need more coffe this morning! Thank you

Comment: Haha, second cup here. That's why I had the answer.

Comment: Clarification: just removing HTML tags may ruin basic formatting (paragraphs and line breaks). E.g.: `<p>Foo</p><p>Bar</p>` -> `FooBar`.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the second param to the strip_tags function

Comment: But `<p>` or `<br>` are meaningless in plain text :-?

Comment: I understand, and good mention. You should have included str_replace in your comment so he could know to replace all `<br />` tags with '\n'

Answer (score 4):

I use:

```
$this->Email->emailFormat('both');

// Convert <br> to \n
$text = preg_replace('/<br(\s+)?\/?>/i', "\n", $html);
// Remove html markup
$text = trim(strip_tags($text));
// Replace multiple (one ore more) line breaks with a single one.
$text = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)+/", "\n", $text);

$this->Email->viewVars(compact('text', 'html'));
```

note that if you foreach, you should reset the email class after each run to avoid issues:

```
$this->Email->reset();
```

Comment: you can also replace more than two newlines to two newlines (if you want to keep paragraphs but still filter 3-xxx newlines due to html markup: `$text = preg_replace("/(\r\n|\r|\n)+(\r\n|\r|\n)+/", "\n\n", $text);`